# spring boot jsp: NoClassDefFoundError TldParser

Tags: spring, spring-boot

NoClassDefFoundError TldParser is thrown while deploying the spring boot application in apache tomcat 7.0.47.

Java version is 1.7
Spring boot version 2.1.7.RELEASE
Added spring boot dependencies: spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-devtools,
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa ,spring-boot-starter-tomcat , tomcat-embed-core ,tomcat-embed-el ,tomcat7-websocket, tomcat-embed-jasper

Added the below dependencies in pom.xml along with the other spring boot dependencies

```
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>


         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-websocket</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.47</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>


         <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
         </dependency>
```

Comment: How is this related to Spring/Spring Boot? Nothing in your question indicates the usage of Spring.

Comment: Don't add code/xml/etc. as comments, please edit your question instead.